# Direct call to objects instantiated by factory on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Considering the module below, how can I make a direct call to `RESTService.get` without relying on AngularJS’ dependency injection?

```js
angular.module('RESTModule', ['ngResource']).
  factory('RESTService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {});
    }
  ]);
```

I expected to be able to create a library method like the one below, doing a direct call to the object created by the factory, but `factory()` does not work as I expected.

```js
var MyLibrary = {};
MyLibrary.method = function() {
  // ...
  // The line below miserably fails... :-(
  angular.module('RESTModule').factory('RESTService').get();
};
```

I may be doing it all wrong, and should consider writing a AngularJS service… but as I am stuck on it I decided to ask for your help.

Thanks!

Side note: I am writing an application that will let developers include their own forms (views) on it, and their own modules to control these views (I am doing fine up to here).

But instead of enforcing them to inject modules (like `RESTModule`) on their own code, I’d like to let them call a “static” library method (like `MYLibrary.method`) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Rory O'Kane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('*[ng-app]')).injector().get('RESTService');
```

should do the job, but you have to make sure that angular has been loaded and completed dependency injection like below:

```js
var restService;
var timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
    if(angular && 
        angular.element(document.querySelector('*[ng-app]')).injector())
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        restService = angular.element(document.querySelector('*[ng-app]')).injector().get('RESTService');
    }}, 1000);
```

Comment: Seems to work! Is there an alternate way to get an injector without referencing a DOM element? In my case I must call angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApplication']) before so I can safely do a angular.element(document).injector(), it's more for self knowledge.

Comment: Maybe you can try angular.injector(["RESTModule"]).get("RESTService"). Retrieving injector from DOM returns injector of angular app running, but this angular.injector([moduleName]) worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

There is one fact. Your method needs $resource to work properly. 
If you are using via Angular, it will inject that dependency for you and the $resource will not be undefined.

If you want to call that method directly, assign that method to a var and call it with your own $resource object.

```
var factoryMethod=function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {});
    };
angular.module('RESTModule', ['ngResource']).
  factory('RESTService', ['$resource', factoryMethod]);
// factoryMethod(<your object>); will work
```

I didn't really get the details about dynamic user given forms. But the method can be called normal.

Comment: The problem with this is that I still depend on a reference to $resource that should be injected. bl0u0l's answer clarified a little bit what I actually need, that is a way to manually get an injector and then get an object from it.

Comment: I was confused. In your question you needed to get object without Angular DI. Thats why I referred my solution. But it seems you need Angular to create your object